# In pytest what does the option string '-xvvv' mean

Tags: command-line-arguments, pytest

Am seeing lots of examples of pytest (py.test) invocations that include the argument string '-xvvv'.  I understand that -x means stop at first fail and a single v means verbose output.  What do the extra v characters signify?

Comment: `pytest --help | grep -i verbose`. Multiple repeats of the flag increase the verbosity level.

Comment: I think of it as `very-very-verbose`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hoefling, @Amit: Thanks! Increasing verbosity it is.